# Java equivalent of openssl blowfish decryption

Tags: java, encryption

I have a file of base64 encoded binary data provided by another system which I can decrypt successfully using the following openssl command line.

```
openssl enc -d -blowfish -a -in base64d_encrypted_content.txt
```

(Unfortunately about all I know about the encryption that's being applied)

In Java, how can I perform the same decryption?

Currently I have...

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    buffer.append(line + "\n");
    line = reader.readLine();
}
reader.close();

BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(buffer.toString());

SecretKeySpec blowfishKey = new SecretKeySpec(password, "Blowfish");
Cipher blowfishCipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
blowfishCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, blowfishKey);
byte[] decryptedBytes = blowfishCipher.doFinal(decodedBytes);
```

but I get the following exception...

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.BlowfishCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching around I ran across [not-yet-commons-ssl](http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/pbe.html) which seems to provide a method replicating the openssl command line in Java...

```
byte[] decrypted = OpenSSL.decrypt("blowfish", password.toCharArray(), base64EncryptedBytes);
```

When I get some time I'll dig into their code and find out exactly what is being done. In the mean time it looks like [OpenSSL.java](http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/src/java/org/apache/commons/ssl/OpenSSL.java) is the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You have  padding fault.  What padding mode was used to encrypt the original cyphertext?  You need to set the Java code to expect that form of padding.

If you don't know then try each of the allowed paddings in turn.  Start with PKCS5/PKCS7 as it is probably the most common.

ETA

Your problem is probably not just padding.  You need to be **certain** all elements are the same at both sides.

- The key must be byte-for-byte identical.
- The mode must be the same: CBC, CTR or ECB (ugh).
- The IV must be the same, byte-for-byte.
- The padding must be the same.

Don't rely on defaults, set all of them explicitly.  With the key and IV, don't check characters, check bytes.

Comment: That makes sense - Do you know what padding the openssl command would be assuming or how I might find that out?

Comment: Just found the list of available options at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#AppA

Comment: Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding"); was the winner. Unfortunately the output is garbled but hopefully I can track down the cause of that - At least garbled output seems like a step forward from an exception.

Comment: How garbled?  First block garbled?  Second and subsequent blocks garbled?  Last block has some junk at the end?  NoPadding means that it doesn't check for padding, so you still might have padding in there, it just wasn't checked.

Comment: It seems to be completely random output. I've managed to get hold of the code which is actually doing the encryption (seems to just call `openssl enc -blowfish -a -salt -in original.txt -out encrypted.txt -pass pass:secret`), so I'm digging into that a bit further in the hope that will tell me what's going on.

Comment: If the output is completely garbled then you problem is likely to be the key.  Check that the keys are **byte for byte** the same, not character for character.  How long is the cyphertext?